# Eclipse git error when pushing to remote: Transport Error: Cannot get remote repository refs

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I started a Static Web Project in Eclipse to share the project in a remote Git repository as a backup and to possibly share with others.

Created a git repository in the project's folder `C:\workspace\projectname`.

Committed (added/staged) everything in the `C:\workspace\projectname` including the `.project` file and everything in the `C:\workspace\projectname\.settings` directory as initial commit (because I thought I want to be able to clone the project again from the repository in the future).

Created a remote repository at [rocketgit](https://www.rocketgit.com) due to its simpler features and ToS.

After everything had been commited, I right clicked the project's repository in the Git Repository view in Eclipse, clicked `Remote` -> `Push`.

I entered `https` as protocol, `rocketgit.com` as host, `users/username/repositoryname` as repository path. Entered my `username` and `password`, clicked `Next`.

But a `Problem Occurred` dialog shows up, with detail `Transport Error:

Cannot get remote repository refs.
https://rocketgit.com/users/username/repositoryname: https://rocketgit.com/users/username/repositoryname/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found`.

How do I resolve this? What does this error mean? Can someone explain a solution. Thanks

Comment: If `.project` and `.settings` are eclipse related, it's better to ignore them from the beginning. Otherwise, co-working contributors would easily encounter merge conflicts. From the error log, it seems you input the repository urls as refs(branches).

Comment: I hvn't created any branches and don't know much about branching yet. From the **Git Repository** view it says my project is: `ProjectName [master] - c:\path-to-it`. I expanded the `Branches` under it, there is `Local` -> `master b1276ed7 commit msg` & `RemoteTracking` folder on level with `Local` folder which is empty. On level with `Branches`, there is `Tags` which is empty, `References` folder -> which contain `HEAD [refs/heads/master] b1276ed7 commit msg`, `Remotes` which is empty, and `Working Tree - c:\path-to-it`. I hvn't modified anything, it's still defaults, anything wrong with that?

Comment: @ElpieKay I guess I was right (to include the `.project` and `.settings`). I was able to clone my Static Web Project back into Eclipse at another laptop, by using `Import` -> `Git`. The only thing I had to remove/modify was the target runtime. I just removed the target runtime (server I use) and I was still able to deploy and run it. Idk what would happen if I didn't include them thou, maybe I will try sometime.

Answer (score 1):

> `users\username\repositoryname` as repository path.

"`users\username\repositoryname`" looks like a path on your disk, not to a remote repo URL.

A proper URL would be `https://yourServer/<user>/<reponame>`, or `ssh://git@yourServer/<user>/<reponame>`.

I don't know which one RockertGit does support, but using GitHub, GitLab or BitBucket would work.

Comment: Sorry. I mistyped the question, fixed it now. I did correctly entered the url. I thought of using GitLab too earlier, but I stated my reasons earlier, will try GitLab later.

Comment: @K4ll-of-D00ty My answer stands: `user/username/reponame` should not be used in a remote URL, only `username/reponame`

Comment: Yes, I mistyped the repo path. It should be `user/<username>/<reponame>`, not `users/<username>/<reponame>` as I misread and mistyped. My bad, because my username starts with 's', therefore my eyes misread it. Your method of just `<username>/<reponame>` works too. Sorry, it was just my eyes mistakes then.. I hv also pushed to GitLab too, the editor at Rocketgit is not highlighted as of this time. I'll just use GitLab from now. Will be trying to clone the project using another laptop soon. Thx for the pointer, if not I might still be stuck for another few extra hours.